# How do I get a User Control's name to display in the designer?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

Some of the standard Windows Forms controls display their name in the designer. A ListBox, for example, will display a dummy item when added to to a form, and that item has the name set for this specific ListBox. So if I change the ListBox's name to "TheFirstListBox", the text "TheFirstListBox" will be displayed inside it.

If I create a UserControl and try to display its name inside it, either in the constructor or in the Load event handler, the type's name (which I assume is the original name for the specific instance) is displayed. So if the type is MyUserControl and the instance's name is set to "TheFirstUserControl", "MyUserControl" is displayed in the designer.

I thought I may be expected to override an OnNameChanged method or add a listener to a NameChanged event and change the displayed text in there but neither of these exist and even if they did I think it wouldn't be a very good solution.

How can I get the string displayed inside a UserControl in the designer (and not at runtime) change when the instance's name changes?

Note: I do have a method that detects whether the control is being instantiated in the designer, and that works. Detecting whether I'm in the designer isn't a problem.

Comment: This actually isn't implemented by any of the controls, they display the value of their Text property.  Which UserControl does not have.  You are looking for the IComponentChangeService.ComponentRenamed event.  It is very hard to use properly, it needs to be implemented in a custom designer.  You'll run head-on into a common crappy restriction, the designer for UserControl is UserControlDocumentDesigner and it is an *internal* class.  Which prevents you from deriving your own from it so you can subscribe the event.

Comment: @HansPassant: I see, I guess that changing the name on a ListBox uses the interface you mentioned to change its (hidden) Text property, and that's what gets displayed?

Comment: You found a good example.  Yes, the ListBoxDesigner class uses IComponentChangeService in its Initialize() method to track a name change.  Also an internal class and not included in the Reference Source, a decompiler can help you see it.